# How to integrate Summernote with S3 image uploading?

Tags: summernote, laravel-backpack

I would like to integrate Summernote's image upload button to upload my images to S3 (actually, I'm using DigitalOcean Spaces, but it's currently using S3 lib, so the integration will be the same, I guess)

I have already run the publish config file command

`php artisan backpack:publish crud/fields/summernote`

then, in `crud_fields_scripts` hook, I inserted this code:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
onImageUpload: uploadImages
});
```

but looks like the `onImageUpload` hook is not gonna run (window.alert works fine though)

please guide me further from this point, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to hook into the already-existed callback tag in the published config file, as follows:

```
let summernotCallbacks = { 
     onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
          element.val(contents).trigger('change');
     },
     onImageUpload: uploadImages
}
```